# Android: Using loops to fill an array with image ID's

Tags: java, android, loops

Similar question to [Android: Set a random image using setImageResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026639/android-set-a-random-image-using-setimageresource), but I think I'm looking for a different answer.

As mentioned in the linked post, this:

```
int p = R.drawable.photo;
image.setImageResource(p);
```

displays photo1, but something like this:

```
String a = "R.drawable.";
String b = "photo";
String c = a+b;
int p = Integer.parseInt(c);
image.setImageResource(p);
```

will not. I have a lot of images, and an array contining all of the image names, so I want to fill an array something like:

```
int imageArray[] = new int[number_of_images];
for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++)
imageArray[i] = ("R.drawable." + image_names[i]);
```

but I get a runtime error. Is there any way to make this loop work? Or better ways to cue up image ID's into an array?

Thanks!

Comment: Try printing p first. Is it the same as R.drawable.photo_id?

Comment: Is your issue similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945678/android-storing-r-drawable-ids-in-xml-array?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method and it will retrun the source id based off a string.  The second and third paramaters are optional but if you can put them in I would.

```
public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

Example:

```
int p = getIdentifier("photo","drawable")
```

Or if you are getting ids all the time you could create a function like:

```
public int getDrawableId(Context context, String name){
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

You just have to check to see if it returns 0 because that means it did not find it.

**EDIT**

For your example up there just impliment the function above and change it to this:

```
int imageArray[] = new int[number_of_images];
for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++)
imageArray[i] = getDrawableId(getApplicationContext(),"R.drawable." + image_names[i]);
```